# Exporting variable values to a separate (.txt) file

Tags: python

I have made code for a project and I am trying to get the final output (a/b) to be outputted to an external text document. I have tried a lot, but nothing is currently working.

```
#SUITABLE GREETING FOR THE USER
print ("Hi Jim, welcome to the bear factory wage calculator program.")

#INPUT bears made
bears_made = int(input("Enter the number of bears you made: "))

#INPUT hours worked
hours_worked = int(input("Enter the number of hours you worked: "))

#ABILITY TO CHANGE THE WAGE PER BEAR AND HOUR
z = str(input("Would you like to change the wage? "))
if z =="yes":
    x = int(input("Enter how much the user should get per bear: "))
    a = bears_made*(x)
    e = int(input("Enter how much the user should get an hour: "))
    b = hours_worked*(e)

else:
    #BEARSMADE x 2 = a
    a = (bears_made *2)

    #HOURSWORKED x 5 = b
    b = (hours_worked *5)


#OUTPUT BIGGER VALUE
if a > b:
    #OUTPUT A
    print ("You earned", a," pounds")
else:
    #OUTPUT B
    print ("You earned", b," pounds")

#f = open("exported.txt",'w') ###This is the area trying to troubleshoot
#text = (a) (b)         
#f.write (text)
#f.close()

#END OF PROGRAM
```

Edit : Sorry, just realised I should add more. I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samho\OneDrive\Desktop\plannedcode.py", line 37, in <module>
    text = (a) (b)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please expand on *"nothing is currently working"* with a [mcve].

Comment: what is `text = (a) (b)` intended to do?

Comment: We understand that you are not experienced, but we still require certain things of your question. In particular, describe exactly what is not working. What output did you expect, what output did you get, and what is the difference?

Comment: I've expanded just a little with the error i'm getting.

Comment: I'm trying to get variables a and b to export onto an external .txt document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you are trying to do. Hope it helps.

```
#SUITABLE GREETING FOR THE USER
print ("Hi Jim, welcome to the bear factory wage calculator program.")

#INPUT bears made
bears_made = int(input("Enter the number of bears you made: "))

#INPUT hours worked
hours_worked = int(input("Enter the number of hours you worked: "))

#ABILITY TO CHANGE THE WAGE PER BEAR AND HOUR
z = str(input("Would you like to change the wage? "))
if z =="yes":
    x = int(input("Enter how much the user should get per bear: "))
    a = bears_made*(x)
    e = int(input("Enter how much the user should get an hour: "))
    b = hours_worked*(e)

else:
    #BEARSMADE x 2 = a
    a = (bears_made *2)

    #HOURSWORKED x 5 = b
    b = (hours_worked *5)


#OUTPUT BIGGER VALUE
if a > b:
    #OUTPUT A
    print ("You earned", a," pounds")
else:
    #OUTPUT B
    print ("You earned", b," pounds")

f = open("exported.txt",'w') ###This is the area trying to troubleshoot
text = str(a)+" "+str(b)
f.write (text)
f.close()

#END OF PROGRAM
```

Comment: thanks, that allows the numbers to copy onto the .txt doc.

Do you know how I can format it? I get a bunch of random decimals on the document (i.e. from entering '20' and '10' i get 0.8 printed on the text document. Thanks

Comment: Tell me an example of what you want as output when you give what as input? And accept the answer if it satisfies your first asked question.

Comment: When you give 20 and 10, and then no, as per your program, what is printed to the text file is-(20*2)/(10*5) = 0.8, which is correct.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - should've been more specific.

I want it to output value **A** and value **B** to a .txt document. I'm not concerned about formatting just yet, but I am just trying to get the two seperate values, a and b, into a text document.

Comment: @SamHockham, made the changes. Please check out the code and accept it, if it fulfills your criteria.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you assign values to `a` and `b`, these two variables have numbers in them, and are of type `int`.

When you run
`text = (a)(b)`
You're essentially calling this: `1(2)`, which is invalid.

I assume you want to output both of those to the text file so replace that statement with this:
`text = "({})({})".format(a, b)`

Comment: When I do that, it prints this to the text doc:
    ({})({}).format(a, b)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
with open('exported.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{0} {1}'.format(a, b))
```

What that does is open the file, then write a string to it.

The string will be the two numbers a and b

Comment: Thank you, this works well. One more question, sorry lol, do you know how to make the code output only the bigger of the 2 values? Couldn't I do this with a basic IF and ELSE statement?

Comment: sure, python has a max function - change the write to: `f.write('{0}'.format(max(a, b)))`